# Is there a documentation available for helper css for material angular?

Tags: angular-material, materialize, angular8

So I am using `angular-cli 8.3.5` and `material-angular 8.2.1`.

I am trying to center my HTML but not finding any document on helper classes.

Does anyone know how to accomplish the task I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/categories

To center you can use Angular-Flex-Layout. (Demos: https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs)

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
```

```
<div fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
   <div>CONTET TO CENTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this mean, `material-angular.io` doesn't have its own helper CSS?

Comment: Do you mean something like Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, how do you control placement otherwise?

Comment: I only know and use flex layout and oldschool css placement. Flex just works fine for me just for example like centering boxes.

Comment: Yes, I think I will have to end up using `@angular/flex-layout` only.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki Official github documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is not centering it vertically is because your div containing the layout-align attribute does not have a height.

Try something like this :

```html
<div class="flexbox-parent">
  <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" style="min-height: 500px">
   <div flex="15">First line</div>
   <div flex="15">Second line</div>
  </div>
</div>
```